# Expanding a widget on tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to be able to resize widget on a Main Window, like in TexMaker. I want that a user clicks on an extreme of the widget and resize it, and the whole elements resize to. Then, I want to press a button and a whole frame appear or disappear.

!https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ln0xUTYKfeOVZQZnVCNmZRTEk/view?usp=sharing

This is a video where I show what exactly what I want to do! Sorry but I don't know how to attach a video here!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `PanedWindow`. The documentation for it can be found here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/panedwindow.htm